# Is it possible to return a boolean and redirect to another page at the same time?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, flashmessenger

I'm calling a method from my JS,

```
[HttpPost]
    public bool Delete(int id, string reason)
    {
        using (IDbConnection dbConnection = DbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection())
        {
            Eorder eorder = Eorder.FetchById(dbConnection, id);
            eorder.Delete(dbConnection, reason, User.Identity.Name, 88, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EorderAttachmentsPath"]);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Which has to return either **true** or **false**.

In my JS I check if it's `.done` / `.failed` etc.

However, I'd also like to add

```
(new DDL.FlashMessenger(HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Context)).AddWarning("Order has been deleted!");
```

And redirect to another page, as the current page (**order**) just got deleted and will throw 404.

Now, I am **not** asking how to redirect to another page with JS, but asking how I could add this FlashMessage to the top of my screen, of my desired webpage. (I could also use `Alert()` or `bootbox.Alert()`, but they're not as appealing as the `FlashMessenger`.

If you've got any ideas, or reccomendations on how I should handle this, please share.

---

Ps. I've found some sources regarding Zend Flashmessenger, but this is **not** the Zend one.

Comment: try with bootstrap dialog boxes. a helpful link. https://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/

Comment: @Deep Yes, thank you. I'm already using those other messages around the site.